# jQuery AlphaNumeric by Paulo P. Marinas - won't disallow certain characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, special-characters, alphanumeric

Hey,
I am using this plugin to prevent characters from being entered into an input field.

http://www.itgroup.com.ph/alphanumeric/

It works very well, except that it does not disallow all. characters it is supposed to.
I am using the following code:

```
$('#dialog-box #label').alphanumeric({allow:"., ?!&+-_/\\"});
```

It is supposed to only allow alphanumeric + the given characters e.g. `?` `!` or `&`. While it works for e.g. in preventing `$` or `)`, you can still write characters like those `~°^§` it guess I guess it has something to do with me having a german keyboard and the CharCodes being different? I added all the characters to the plugin to be forbidden, but it does not help.

Some, like `°` and `§` can be disallowed by using the function twice and the second time using the ichars with them. But others like `~` and `^` will still not be deleted.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

// Update
I used the console and found out, that `^` and `~` do not appear when typed. They seem to not be recognized by charCode. Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little late, but I found this. http://blog.treyhunner.com/2010/10/replacement-for-jquery-alphanumeric.html Maybe a useful alternative.

Comment: Not too late in any case. I did not get anything to work and pushed it off for later. I will check it out soon. Thank you.